# Http proxy options in android app development

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app in which I want to use `http proxy` options (like open vpn custom http headers)

I want to use `socks proxy` with `custom http headers` as `host` and `x-online-host`.

For example in my college "youtube.com" is blocked and "google.com" isn't blocked.

So I want my application to connect to youtube.com and fetch response by fooling the college server that I am connecting to "google.com"

I have searched the Internet for sample code but i haven't found… Please help me.

Here is my code (don't know why not working):

```
public String getdata() throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    String proxyadd = "141.0.11.253";

  try{
        HttpParams httpP = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpP, 2000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpP, 2000);
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("youtube.com");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setParams(httpP);
        request.setURI(website);


        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyadd, 80);
        System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
        client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
        request.setHeader("Host", "http://google.com");



        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(code == 200){
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.seperator");

         while((l = in.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(l+nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy for post method:

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.youflik.youflik.utils.Util;
import android.util.Log;


public class HttpPostClient {
    private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";
    public static int statuscode;

    public static JSONObject sendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

            StringEntity se;

            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

            // Set HTTP parameters
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");


            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");


            StatusLine statusline = response.getStatusLine();
            statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();


            // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // Read the content stream
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                // convert content stream to a String

                try {

                    String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
                    instream.close();
                    // Transform the String into a JSONObject
                    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

                    return jsonObjRecv;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("converted string is "+sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }



}
proxy for get method
public class HttpGetClient {
    public static int statuscode;

    public static JSONObject sendHttpPost(String URL){

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient;
            httpclient = HttpClientSingalTon.getHttpClienttest();
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(URL);
            if(Util.API_TOKEN !=null)
            {
                System.out.println(Util.API_TOKEN);

            }

            HttpResponse response;

            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpGetRequest.getRequestLine());
            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpGetRequest.getMethod());
            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpGetRequest.getFirstHeader("X-Auth-Token"));
            //  System.out.println("executing request Tsting  " + httpGetRequest.getHeaders("X-Auth-Token"));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpGetRequest);

            StatusLine statusline = response.getStatusLine();
            statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);

                // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
                instream.close();
                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(result);

                return jsonObjRecv;

            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }       


}
```